# Visual Studio 2022, how to enable auto generation with two tabs instead of one?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2019, when generating auto complete statements, I have to press Tab twice to output the snippet. I have built up muscle memory for that over the years and now in VS 2022 it seems to be a mix of one tab and two. Is there a setting that I can make it always two tabs?

Example: Create a new C# class and go to add a property. If you type "prop", in the past it would be "tab tab" to then output the property statement and it would auto select the type to allow me to type and change it. Now the first tab outputs the line and then the next tab makes it move from the type part of the statement to the variable name. I then have to go back to edit the type afterwards.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT The way you just described it though is not how it is working. When you press Tab once it auto completes the line and automatically selects the "type" so you can replace it. You described it as one tab to output the line and then another tab to select the type. That would have been the double tab method I was talking about in the past. Also the tabbing is inconsistent with other areas such as an if foreach tab tab still works the old way where tab tab writes out the statement and selects the first var.

Comment: Sorry for this design in the latest Visual Studio. I understand your inconvenience. In previous versions, the current changes were made due to feedback from many users that they wanted to insert blocks of code with a "Tab". Press the "Tab" key for the first time to select the smart prompt code and modify the attribute type, and press the "Tab" key for the second time to modify the attribute name. This is still in line with most people's usage habits. If more people are not used to it, there is still a chance to restore the two "Tab" operations next time the version changes.